# Export full callstack/backtrace from `xctrace` report

Tags: xcode, rust, instruments, backtrace

Context: We're trying to add `xctrace` support for [inferno](https://github.com/jonhoo/inferno), a rust library used to generate flamegraphes. [Actual issue can be found here](https://github.com/jonhoo/inferno/issues/246). This question was previously asked on apple developer forums, [without luck so far](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/708957).

Flamegraphes are built by aggregating CPU samples to see which functions are hot.
To do so we need to have access to the full callstack for each sample, **however when exporting a trace with `xctrace export`, the callstack is cropped**.

Steps to reproduce the issue:

1. run `$ xctrace record --template 'System Trace' --output PATH/TO/TRACE/FILE.trace --launch YOUR_PROCESS_NAME`, and wait for the given process to finish.
2. run `$ xctrace export --output foo.xml --input PATH/TO/TRACE/FILE.trace --xpath '/trace-toc/run[@number="1"]/data/table[@schema="time-sample"]` 3. open `foo.xml`, and check the rows

Note: `xctrace export` have several export schema available but `time-sample` seems to be the one containing the callstack.

Sample row:

```xml
<row>
  <sample-time id="22" fmt="00:00.039.455">39...</sample-time>
  <thread ref="2"/>
  <process ref="4"/>
  <core ref="14"/>
  <thread-state ref="8"/>
  <weight ref="9"/>
  <backtrace id="23" fmt="test::test::foo ← (11 other frames)">
    <process ref="4"/>
    <text-addresses id="24" fmt="frag 1732">4331406713 4331406716</text-addresses>
    <process ref="4"/>
    <text-addresses id="25" fmt="frag 1733">4331403 ...</text-addresses>
  </backtrace>
</row>
```

As one can see the callstack/backtrace is cropped "(11 other frames)", however according to the apple `Instrument.app`'s (Apple's GUI to read `xctrace` reports) [documentation it is possible to have it listed and symbolicated](https://help.apple.com/instruments/developer/mac/current/#/dev15401019):

> In extended views, the entire symbolicated backtrace is listed.

I was unable to find how to export the extended view.

Another option would be to symbolicate the backtrace using the `text-addresses` if those are trustable. [That question was asked a year ago on apple developers forums, without answer so far](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/683580).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from Xcode 14.3, `xctrace export` contains the fully desymbolicated backtraces.

You can start a recording with either of these commands:

- `xctrace record --template 'Time Profiler' --launch <executable> --output tmp.trace`
- `xctrace record --template 'Time Profiler' --attach <pid|proc_name> --output tmp.trace`

then extract the time profile from it:
`xctrace export --input tmp.trace --xpath '/trace-toc/run[@number="1"]/data/table[@schema="time-profile"]'`